# Forcing call with array to resolve as varargs invocation

Tags: java, casting, jvm, variadic-functions, type-inference

Alright, so I have a function like

```
public static UnorderedList newUnorderedList(Object... items) {
    return new UnorderedList(
        stream(items)
            .peek(e -> checkNotNull(e, "Cannot create null list item"))
            .map(e -> {
                if (e instanceof Component) return newListItem((Component) e);
                if (e instanceof String) return newListItem((String) e);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("List item must be String or Component but is neither: " + e.getClass().getName());
            }).toArray(ListItem[]::new)
    );
}
```

(**EDIT**: Note: the `UnorderedList` here, is Vaadin's implementation of an html `<ul>` tag, I'm not trying to get a java list.)

This will trigger a warning when you call it with an array saying that it's unclear whether you want to treat the array itself as a single element or as a container for the elements.

Don't immediately see an elegant way out of this. I like neither of these:

- always cast to `Object[]`
- turn `Object...` into `Collection<Object>`

Is there an annotation or something that would let the compiler know to always resolve arrays to vararg calls on annotated methods? (On the method declaration, not the call sites.)

Comment: what is UnorderedList and why don't create a collector that returns unordered list?

Comment: Have you tried using `Arrays.stream(items)`

Comment: @lscoughlin Sorry, didn't think it would be relevant. `UnorderedList` is Vaadin's implementation for a html `<ul>` tag.

Comment: @LazarPetrovic to do what with exactly? I'm already using it in `stream(items)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can overload the method:

```
public static UnorderedList newUnorderedList(Object first, Object... other) {
    return newUnorderedListImpl(Stream.concat(Stream.of(first), Arrays.stream(other)));
}
public static UnorderedList newUnorderedList(Object[] items) {
    return newUnorderedListImpl(Arrays.stream(items));
}
private static UnorderedList newUnorderedListImpl(Stream<?> items) {
    return new UnorderedList(
        items
            .peek(e -> checkNotNull(e, "Cannot create null list item"))
            .map(e -> {
                if (e instanceof Component) return newListItem((Component) e);
                if (e instanceof String) return newListItem((String) e);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("List item must be String or Component but is neither: " + e.getClass().getName());
            }).toArray(ListItem[]::new)
    );
}
```

Then, a call with an existing array will end up at `newUnorderedList(Object[] items)` whereas an actual varargs call would end up at `newUnorderedList(Object first, Object... other)`, even when only one argument has been specified, as long as that argument is not an array. Since the single argument is supposed to be either, a `String` or `Component`, this is not a problem.

The only possibility which has been lost with these two methods, is the ability to call the method without an argument. If this is a problem, you need to add another overload:

```
public static UnorderedList newUnorderedList() {
    return newUnorderedListImpl(Stream.empty());
}
```

Comment: An interesting solution. Could you maybe explain why this doesn't suffer from the same issue as the `varargs` approach? Shouldn't java have just as much trouble deciding whether I want to call the method with the array argument or the method with the object argument and an additional empty array?

Comment: When you have a method `m(Object)` and a method `m(Object[])` and call `m` with an array, the method `m(Object[])` has precedence, which is the old "call the most specific method" rule, which existed even long before varargs were added to Java. In fact, Java does not even consider the varargs method when another matching method without varargs exists. You would now run into the same problem as before, if you wanted to call `newUnorderedList(anObject, anArray)`, but this usage was not on your wish list, so if someone wants to use it that way, they have to live with needing a disambiguation.

Answer (score 0):

You're making an UnorderedList the wrong way.

Assuming it's a collection:

```
    Object[] objects = new Object[]{1, "hello", "there", "george"};
    LinkedList<AtomicReference<?>> list = Arrays.stream(objects)
            .filter(Objects::nonNull)
            .map(e -> {
                if (e instanceof Integer) return new AtomicReference<>(e);
                if (e instanceof StringBuilder) return new AtomicReference<>(e);
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("PAIN");
            })
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
```

Comment: And  if we assume that `UnorderedList` is just a bad name for an array-based type? By the way,  the code primarily builds an array that is the argument for the constructor of `UnorderedList` …

Comment: You assumed wrong. It's Vaadin's implementation of an html `<ul>` tag. It *receives* a varargs of `Components`, hence the array. Added that information to the question.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, I guess that you want to do the following:

```
Object [] items = new Object [x];
items [0] = new Object [] {"Object1", "Object2", "Object3"};
var result = newUnorderedList( items );
```

This will treat the array with the String as a single item, causing the exception, while calling

```
var result = newUnorderedList( items [0] );
```

would return 3 elements for `result`.

There is no annotation that forces the handling of a single array as a single item instead of a list of items. Have fun with a signature like this:

```
Object function( Object [] ... );
```

Comment: Quite on the contrary, I'd like to pass an array and treat it as the varargs arguments. The problem, here, is that `Object[]` IS an `Object` so the function -- as per the warning -- isn't sure which way I want it treated unless I cast it to either.